# Wrong path to image, css, javascript etc. when using protocol-relative URL

Tags: html, security, ssl, drupal

when I turned on SSL on my Drupal 7 website I've also turned on module to replace all images, styles, etc. path from 
`src="http://example.com/path/to/my/image.jpg"` to 
`"//example.com/path/to/my/image.jpg"`.

I've noticed, that right now I have a lot of page not found (404) in my log, and they look like `https://example.com/example.com/path/to/my/image/jpg`.

Do You know, what can I do to prevent this 404 errors? Maybe some htaccess redirect? Do You think It's fault of old web browsers which don't support protocol-relative URL?

Comment: If the images are on the same domain, could you not just use `/path/to/my/image.jpg` then it will pick up the protocol and domain name automatically

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and this addition to .htaccess seems to have resolved it for me:

```
RewriteRule ^//example.com/(.*)$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

My theory is that those 404 errors were the result of some poorly written bots crawling the website or some non-standard browsers that don't support protocol relative URLs. Normal browsers add the proper protocol to the URLs before accessing the server, so in theory the server shouldn't ever see such URLs in the requests.